# Extracting XML sub-tags from a clob in Oracle via SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath

**I have the following CLOB XML Fragment in the DB attribute "object_body":**

```
<object stamp="8fc630bd-f1f5-43ac-b9d2-3b9db9054c75_1481811010527" type="Aggregation" version="12">
  <property name="name" value="COA_Cash_Position" valueType="string"/>
  <property name="description" value="COA_Cash_Position" valueType="string"/>
  <property name="objectId" value="ef4296f1-6af6-4de8-83fe-fa01cf327d87" valueType="string"/>
  <property name="branchId" value="01ecc9ed-27f3-42cb-a44d-2cec221ec8fa" valueType="string"/>
  <property name="models" valueType="table">
    <object type="ModelBasedTask:modelEntry" version="3">
      <property name="dataModel" valueType="url">DataModel["ModifyModel[COA_Cash_Positions_BHS_Unadjusted].STAGING:X_NRS_BSL40K_BHS"{ModifyModel[ff81e5f2-2ef6-437a-b113-67f7c0dd5e53].cdf308fc-520d-4611-a8db-4e6863e216b8:9ffcd08e-732a-4270-b15f-f4775bcc69db}]</property>
      <property name="instanceSelectionRule" valueType="object">
        <object type="InstanceSelectionRule" version="3">
          <property name="instanceDateRule" valueType="object">
            <object type="InstanceSelectionRule:rule" version="3">
              <property name="type" value="EQUAL" valueType="string"/>
            </object>
          </property>
          <property name="instanceKeyRules" valueType="table"/>
        </object>
      </property>
    </object>
  </property>
</object>
```

Aim is to extract the value of the property tag with name=”description” 

=> to produce “COA_Cash_Position”

Tried all variations of:

```
EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(object.object_body), '/object/property[@name="description"].getStringVal()'),
```

If I loose the .getStringVal() the query works but obviously only provides empty results (as the property tag itself doesn't include any value).

Get mostly error messages the likes of:

ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '/object/property[@name="description"].
getStringVal()'

What easily works is extracting the values between two xml tags but getting a specific property value (like here the "value" of the  tag with name="description") seems to evade the XML extract possibilities.

Any help is warmly appreciated...

Comment: Your xml is not good. It contains errors.

Comment: The ORA-19202 error is because you are trying to use getStringVal() in an Xpath. It's not an Xpath function, it's an Oracle function on an XMLType object.

Comment: @MT0 are sure that you put right enclosing tags? I can fix it in couple ways, which is right only author knows.

Comment: @Seyran The semantic meaning of the fix is independent to the correctness of the answer of the problem - the example could be stripped back to the bare minimum and all the nested object stripped out and it would still not affect the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`EXTRACTVALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions069.htm#SQLRF06173) is deprecated in Oracle 12 - it is being replaced by [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm#SQLRF06232) or [`XMLQUERY`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions265.htm#SQLRF06209).

```
SELECT x.description
FROM   your_table t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '//object/'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.your_clob_column )
         COLUMNS description VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './property[@name="description"]/@value'
       ) x;
```

or

```
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         '//object/property[@name="description"]/@value'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( your_clob_column )
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ).getStringVal()
FROM   your_table;
```

But if you do want to use `EXTRACTVALUE` you can do:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(
         XMLTYPE( your_clob_column ),
         '//object/property[@name="description"]/@value'
       )
FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks MTO, this was exactly what I was looking for. Also great help from the others but I concur that the XPATH alternative is the most reliable especially if I have many large and autogenerated (and thus messy) XML objects. Thanks agin big time…

Comment: Almost there - ;=)  If the XML is constructed as messy as the ones I'm dealing with, new issues appear: <br> Is there an XPATH way to only select the first property with the name="description" but not the subsequent ones (in the same single record XML object)?

Comment: @TomDebus `'//object/property[@name="description"][1]/@value'`

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch, this actually solved my issue. Will have to dive deeper into XPath as a next learning objective. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the value of the attribute @value the path you want is

```
/object/property[@name='description']/@value
```

Answer (score -1):

Your XML contains some errors.
We can achieve your expected output using REGEXP in oracle.
Check below query.

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR (object_body, 'description" value=".*.".v', 1), 'description" value="', '', 1, 1) ,'" v','',1,1)   
 FROM Table
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/EHLJ16485) here.

Output IS: **`COA_Cash_Position`**

Comment: What happens if the `value` and `name` attributes are swapped? The XML still has exactly the same attributes and meaning for that tag but your query will break. Or, if another attribute is added to the tag between the `name` and `value` attributes. Or, if another tag is added before that one which is `<property name="otherdescription" value="don't want this" />`.

Comment: Then change query as per requirement @MT0 .

Comment: The point is not that the requirement has changed but that the requirement is the same and the data has changed order but not changed the semantic meaning of the data. Using XPATH, for any of the 3 situations I presented in the previous comment the XML, would get the correct answer but your regular expression will not. Regular expressions are, except in a limited set of circumstances, the [wrong solution for parsing XML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1509264) (see the top 3 answers).

Comment: Dear Mr Bhosale, thanks for your answer. While your solution works perfectly unfortunately the XML is so messy, that it contains the same property name (description) many times over. And I'm only interested in the first occurence within each record / clob object.

Comment: @TomDebus welcome . i have give another solution rather than XML.if its work then mark plz or vote

Comment: Regular expressions are not the tool for general parsing of XML and while they may work in limited circumstances they are not capable of handling the same grammars. This can be simply solved using a proper XML parser with the XPATH `'//object/property[@name="description"][1]/@value'`. If the XML is messy then it just reinforces my first comment in that it would be quite easy for the attributes to be swapped in some instances or some of the other issues I mentioned to occur.