# How to extract values from a single xmltype tag into different columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

I have a xmltype column in a table which contains the following tag

```
<LOCATION TYPE="ABS" EPSG="4277" UNIT="decLL">
      <X>-2.12105834</X>
      <Y>49.20372223</Y>
    </LOCATION>
```

I have extracted the values for type in a column using the following query

```
SELECT a.object_id,a.xml_data.extract('//LOCATION/@TYPE').getStringVal() AS "Location Type"
FROM   object_history a;
```

The output is ABSABSREL in a single column in a table.
I want to get each value in a separate column in a table.
Please help with how can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting XML sub-tags from a clob in Oracle via SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362969/extracting-xml-sub-tags-from-a-clob-in-oracle-via-sql)

Comment: NO, the values have been extracted correctly but i want them to appear in separate columns

Comment: The sample you provided cannot return such a value, because it looks like you have more entries with the same tag and xpath returns a sequence. If you know the maximum number of elements in it, you may access them by position (`[n]`), if no, then there's no way as SQL result set in Oracle should have predefined structure

Comment: I tried to put index after type as type[1] but still it is returning multiple values

Comment: Please, provide reproducible example with appropriate sample data and the output for it

Comment: Apologies i don't have any reproducible output and can  not share the above one but i can explain i am working on a telecom project in which the above <location> tags are stored in a xmltype column and the resulting values are ABSABSREL where ABS is for a property and ABS and REL are for 2 antennas but in xml type column only one ABS are shown . i don't even know why on extracting it shows 3 different values though only one is present in xmltype tag

Comment: @ANCHALBHASIN Of course you can share reproduceable output; you just make up fake data that replicates the issue rather than sharing the real proprietary data. However, if you really cannot reproduce the problem then how do you expect us to provide a solution?

Comment: @ANCHALBHASIN Reproducible example means that you may reproduce **the functionality**, not the data. We do not care if you have some specific values or it is a fake data where each, e.g. `'ABC'` is replaced by `'DEF'`. It doesn't really matter what is the source if you may transform the data in the answer back to get the solution for your problem. Please, consider, for example, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18) to reproduce your problem in sandbox environment, then post DDL, inserts and your query that may show what is the issue. Currently it is not reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XMLTABLE`:

```sql
SELECT object_id,
       x.*
FROM   object_history h
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/LOCATION'
         PASSING h.xml_data
         COLUMNS
           type VARCHAR2(3)  PATH './@TYPE',
           epsg NUMBER       PATH './@EPSG',
           unit VARCHAR2(10) PATH './@UNIT',
           x    NUMBER       PATH './X',
           y    NUMBER       PATH './Y'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE object_history ( object_id, xml_data ) AS
SELECT 1, XMLTYPE('<LOCATION TYPE="ABS" EPSG="4277" UNIT="decLL"><X>-2</X><Y>49</Y></LOCATION>') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, XMLTYPE('<LOCATION TYPE="ABS" EPSG="4277" UNIT="decLL"><X>-1</X><Y>50</Y></LOCATION>') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, XMLTYPE('<LOCATION TYPE="REL" EPSG="4277" UNIT="decLL"><X>0</X><Y>51</Y></LOCATION>') FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | OBJECT_ID | TYPE | EPSG | UNIT | X | Y |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | ABS | 4277 | decLL | -2 | 49 |
> | 2 | ABS | 4277 | decLL | -1 | 50 |
> | 3 | REL | 4277 | decLL | 0 | 51 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc04197a04e698016e671eac117603a9)*